# UIAutomation: accessibilityIdentifier of a table cell not reflected in automation script.

Tags: ios5, ios-ui-automation

Setting accessibilityIdentifier property of a table cell in Xcode 4.2 (iOS SDK 5.0).
The name is not reflected when accessed in automation Script (Instruments 4.2).

Comment: What is the exact view hierarchy? Have you rebuilt the application?